# How can I pick out a token from a string, in ksh/bash?

Tags: shell, parsing

I imagine this must have been asked several times, but I simply can't find a good match; sometimes you just can't think of the right search, I suppose.

So, this is my problem - I want to analyse SQL strings like the following in a script:

```
select * from my_table where col1 = #ABC# and col2 like "%#DEF#%";
```

I want to, somehow, fish out the tokens `ABC` and `DEF` by parsing for the delimiting `#`s. Trying with `sed`, I get something like:

```
# echo "something#ABC#else" | sed 's/.*\(#..*#\).*/\1/g'
#ABC#
```

but that only catches one, if there are more:

```
# echo "something#ABC#else something#DEF#else" | sed 's/.*\(#..*#\).*/\1/g'
#DEF#
```

It seems I'm pursuing the wrong lines here - is there a better way?

Comment: what would you expect as output from the string: "something#ABC#DEF#else" ?  'ABC' and 'DEF'? 'ABC' and 'else' (to to end of string for missing '#')? just ABC?

Comment: The shell is the wrong tool for this task. Use a general-purpose programming language (Python, C, Haskell, Ruby, Perl, Rust, Go, ... pick one.)

Comment: @markp - I'm not fuzzy, really; actually, the purpose is two-fold: first, to generate a list of the tokens, so I can ask the user for the values, and next to replace the '#XYZ#' strings with the values that are received. So, for the user interaction, I'd probably use the naked tokens, but I'll have to replace the full strings, incl '#'

Comment: @chepner: I have reasons for working with shell script. Doing this in C would be simple, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- there are an even number of delimiters (`#`), eg, '#ABC#def#GHI#' would be valid but '#ABC#def#' would not be valid
- the output should not include the delimiter
- each parsed token is placed on a separate/new line
- we're interested in **ALL** characters (not just letters/numbers) that fall between a pair of delimiters

With an even number of delimiters we can have `awk` display the even numbered fields, eg:

```
$ echo "something#ABC#else something#DEF#else" | awk -F"#" '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) { print $i } }'
ABC
DEF
```

- `-F"#"` - designate `#` as `awk's` input field delimiter
- `for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2)` - loop through our even numbered fields using `i` as our index
- `print $i` - print the `ith` field

Or if you want to eliminate the subshell (invoked by `echo ... |`) you could use a here string:

```
$ awk -F"#" '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i+=2) { print $i } }' <<< "something#ABC#else something#DEF#else"
ABC
DEF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "something#ABC#else something#DEF#else" | grep -oP '(?<=#)[A-Z0-9a-z]+(?=#)'
ABC
DEF
```

Using grep [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I'm now faced with the conundrum of choosing between accepting your or the one from @markp, both of which are good. I will think about this :-)

Comment: A suggestion: you would choose based on what works the best for your scenario and if they are equal, then use the timeline of an answer, i.e., who answered first.